# Second quantized $S^2$ operator in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

Is it possible to obtain easily the second quantized $S^2$ operator in Qiskit, preferably from [ElectronicStructureProblem](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization.ElectronicStructureProblem.html)?

I'm obtaining Hamiltonian via [second_q_ops()](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization.ElectronicStructureProblem.second_q_ops.html#qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization.ElectronicStructureProblem.second_q_ops) method, accessing property `ElectronicEnergy`. Is something similar possible to obtain $S^2$?

I know, that this functionality is easily accessible in [OpenFermion](https://quantumai.google/openfermion) via [s_squared_operator](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/openfermion/hamiltonians/s_squared_operator) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In Nature there is the angular momentum operator which is S-squared (built via the `AngularMomentum` property class). The `second_q_ops()` link above refers to this as one of the operators which is available in the return.